Set RPS with ethers.js
I wrote a code to check the pending transactions of a contract, but I would like to limit the RPS (requests per second) to 25 (I'm using a node with user free) how could I do it?
Here is the code:
const ethers = require("ethers");
const InputDataDecoder = require('ethereum-input-data-decoder')
const ABI = require("./ABI.json");
const url = "wss://bsc-mainnet.core.chainstack.com/ws/API-KEY";

const decoder = new InputDataDecoder(ABI);

const init = function () {

  const provider = new ethers.WebSocketProvider(url);

  provider.on("pending", async (tx) => {
    provider.getTransaction(tx).then(function (transaction) {
        if (transaction.to === '0x24...') {
            const data = transaction.data
            const decodedData = decoder.decodeData(data);
            console.log("DECODE DATA: ", decodedData)
            //console.log(transaction)
        }
      })})
};

init();

Thank you for your help :)

To limit the requests per second (RPS) to 25, you can implement a throttling mechanism in your code.
Here's the revised code:
const ethers = require("ethers");
const InputDataDecoder = require('ethereum-input-data-decoder')
const ABI = require("./ABI.json");
const url = "wss://bsc-mainnet.core.chainstack.com/ws/API-KEY";

const decoder = new InputDataDecoder(ABI);

const init = function () {
  const provider = new ethers.WebSocketProvider(url);
  let lastRequestTime = 0;
  const requestInterval = 1000 / 25; // 25 requests per second

  provider.on("pending", async (tx) => {
    const now = Date.now();
    const timeSinceLastRequest = now - lastRequestTime;
    if (timeSinceLastRequest < requestInterval) {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, requestInterval - timeSinceLastRequest));
    }

    lastRequestTime = Date.now();

    provider.getTransaction(tx).then(function (transaction) {
      if (transaction.to === '0x24...') {
        const data = transaction.data
        const decodedData = decoder.decodeData(data);
        console.log("DECODE DATA: ", decodedData)
        //console.log(transaction)
      }
    })
  });
};

init();

P.S., You can adjust the requestInterval variable if you want to change the rate limit.
